# How could this question pass the code-only filter?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting, quality-filter

I understand that the [code-only filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107068/168269) can't be too stringent. However, this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24457078/861716 contains *nothing but* code. (And it's a poor question for other reasons).

The first version had a few comment lines that were not indented. I can imagine these were seen as plain text. But shouldn't the edit have been bounced?

Comment: Looks like "Not a question" to me ... Anyway, I had the impression those quality filters only apply on asking and not on editing, especially not for someone with 2k+ rep like happened.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure, it's not a question and it should have been closed right away. I understand from Marc Gravell's words that the filter also applies to questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[First revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24457078/1) of the question is indeed code only. **But** it is badly formatted.

Meaning that the code-only filter was fooled to think it wasn't code-only and let it pass.

Case of the really bad question being so bad it fooled the naive filter.

Marking with [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) given that the filter works as intended...

Comment: Seems like the "unformatted code" test was fooled first. Or doesn't that block submitting?

Comment: @Deduplicator - well, there was some formatted code. But it all started with `//` (i.e. comments), so it probably got fooled too. Not a bad idea to add `//` (if it doesn't use it already).

Comment: Seems likely that the user broke the code formatting intentionally to get around the block. It wouldn't be the first time. I'm somewhat pacified by the fact that you left the [bug] tag in place while marking this [status-bydesign].