# How to deal with post containing only code

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, answers, code

How should I deal with stuff that contains only code (both question, "*here code, fix it*" and answer that has just a bunch of lines and not comment at all)?

Is:

- for answer: flagging it as "*This is commentary on another post, not an answer*",
- for question: flagging it as "*code isn't working*" without proper effort,

is enough? Or should I do something more / something else?

BTW: I have got absolutely no idea, that we have something like "[code-only filter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261853/1469208)" here. But, I'm pretty sure, that it isn't quite working as I have to deal with such posts over and over again, every day.

Comment: It actually answers half of your question regarding answers, isn't it? So you could just try to apply similar approach to questions, couldn't you?

Comment: @Gas In points: (1) it answers only half of my question, (2) it actually answers nothing, since linked question has no answer, only bunch of comments, (3) flagging a question as duplicate and voting to close it will stop others answersing it (if it gets closed), (4) I think I heard, that marking a question as duplicate of a question, that has no answer, isn't to good idea. I fully understand, that it is easier (and way quicker) to VTC question instead of actually answering it, but this isn't a point here. At least, I think so.

Comment: Just curious as to examples of questions you run into that are code-only? Because if they still exist, then obviously action will be taken once you bring attention to it.

Comment: Ok, no problem. If it doesn't help you. Closing withdrawn, be cool ;)

Comment: [Everyone just be cool](http://cdn2.thegloss.com/wp-content/gallery/one-night-stand/be-cool.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> for answer: flagging it as "This is commentary on another post, not an answer",

No, this is not appropriate because it **is an answer** just not a very good quality answer.

I will typically downvote and comment. If it is a new user then I may just comment and if it isn't changed within a codeMagic-suitable time then I downvote. If it is not a new user then the -codeMagic-suitable time limit is zero as they should know better.

> for question: flagging it as "code isn't working" without proper effort,

That is appropriate (assuming you are talking about closing as

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

) because the "clear problem statement" portion clearly has not been met.

I also would downvote and comment.

You may notice that the word "comment" is in all of my theoretical situations. Just sayin'...

Comment: +1 for `codeMagic-suitable time`. What is the equation for defining value of this variable? :>

Comment: @trejder it's a secret ;)

Comment: I was doing this (commenting on how a description should be added to the answer so it's not only code), and found that people feel attacked and fight back with comments like "everyone knows what that code does" or "the code speaks for itself". How would you deal with that type of situations in an appropriate way?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro assuming you are suggesting a description in a polite manner, I will usually respond with something similar to, "You and I may know what the code does and why it should work. But, since the OP is asking, you can't expect them to understand without some simple explanation. A little bit of a description can help everyone." Then I would probably downvote, if I hadn't already.

Comment: I have run into people like that, as well, but more times than not, people seem to respond positively too it or not at all. All we can do is try and people who truly want to help the site and don't just care about points, will take kindly to it and update the answer.